# salesforce web to lead with "notes"

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to use Web to Lead functionality of salesforce. I can create a lead, but the Notes field does not get the data I supplied in the form. Here's the form I'm sending:

```html
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="oid" value="xxxxxxx">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.mycompany.com">

<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="company">Company</label><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>

Notes:<textarea  id="00N6100000C5D5Z" name="00N6100000C5D5Z" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>

<label for="street">Street</label><textarea name="street"></textarea><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Every field gets populated in the new lead entry, except Notes. Has anyone ran into this issue? How did you resolve it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got why you have specified **type="text"** with your textarea. Textarea itself is a type.

Can you replace

> Notes:`<textarea  id="00N6100000C5D5Z" name="00N6100000C5D5Z" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>`

With:

> Notes:`<textarea  id="00N6100000C5D5Z" name="00N6100000C5D5Z" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>`

Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not make any difference. Salesforce must be handling the field names differently (the notes is a form field that has the name '00N61000xxx' but others have less cryptic names.